# pygame drawing in the terminal instead of a separate window

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to draw something pretty simple using pygame. I have a file draw.py, which I'm running by simply typing python draw.py That's how I'm initializing the screen in the code.

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
```

Weirdly, instead of starting an external window, things get drawn in the terminal, making the drawing some kind of ASCII art. I tried doing different things, such as running pygame.init() or pygame.display.init() after importing pygame but there is something I don't understand about pygame.

I would like pygame to open a separate graphical window and draw things there. How can I achieve that?

(If that makes any difference, I'm sshing (with -X) to the machine on which I'm working).

Comment: Ah yes, that almost certainly does make a difference. Have you [set up the machine to enable X11 forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772)?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I'm curious about how it looks.

Comment: @Ari Cooper-Davis. You were right. I was because of the settings of X11.

Comment: @skrx That's what it looks like. https://ibb.co/i8qqO5

Answer (score 0):

You have to [set up the machine to enable X11 forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely/12772#12772):

> X11 forwarding needs to be enabled on both the client side and the server side.
>
> On the **client side**, the `-X` (capital X) option to `ssh` enables X11 forwarding, and you can make this the default (for all connections or for a specific connection) with `ForwardX11 yes` in `~/.ssh/config`.
>
> On the **server side**, `X11Forwarding` yes must be specified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Note that the default is no forwarding (some distributions turn it on in their default `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), and that the user cannot override this setting.